# Is there another way to find the authenticated user or my auth middleware does not work?

Tags: mongodb, authentication, mongoose, jwt

i am trying to create a route where i create a cart based on the authenticated user. It uses jsonwebtoken for the authentication. it creates a cart but in the name field of the cart it puts the first user in the database instead of the name of the authenticated user.

**Cart creation route**

```
const createCart = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
  const user = await User.findOne({ user: req.user._id });
  const existingCart = await Cart.findOne({ name: user.name });
  if (existingCart) {
    res.status(200).json(existingCart);
  } else {
    const cart = await Cart.create({
      name: user.name,
      items: [],
    });
    const savedCart = await cart.save();
    res.status(201).json(savedCart);
  }
});
cartRoutes.route("/").post(protectRoute, createCart);
```

**auth Middleware**

```
import jwt from "jsonwebtoken";
import asyncHandler from "express-async-handler";
import User from "../models/User.js";

const protectRoute = asyncHandler(async (req, res, next) => {
  let token;

  if (req.headers.authorization && req.headers.authorization.startsWith("Bearer")) {
    try {
      token = req.headers.authorization.split(" ")[1];
      const decoded = jwt.verify(token, process.env.TOKEN_SECRET);

      req.user = User.findById(decoded.id);

      next();
    } catch (error) {
      res.status(401);
      throw new Error("You are not a user");
    }
  }
  if (!token) {
    res.status(401);
    throw new Error("Not authrized, no token");
  }
});

export default protectRoute;
```

i tried findById() to find the authenticated user but it returned null